# SecEdit with powershell to load local security rights

Tags: powershell

I have over 100 non-domain joined computers I must setup the local security settings on. I am trying to use the secedit command.

Here is the Exported command from the orignal.

```
Secedit /export /db C:\Windows\security\database\secedit.sdb /mergedpolicy /cfg c:\temp\Sec.inf /log C:\Temp\secedit.log /quiet
```

Export was successful with no errors. I copied the file to another computer and ran with the following command with PowerShell:

```
SecEdit.exe /import /DB C:\Windows\security\database\secedit.sdb /cfg c:\temp\Sec.inf /overwrite /quiet /log c:\temp\secedit_import.log
```

No change occurred. I then used the configure command as followed with PowerShell:

```
SecEdit.exe /Configure /DB C:\Windows\security\database\secedit.sdb /cfg C:\temp\Sec.inf /overwrite /quiet /log c:\temp\secedit_Configure.log
```

The Log presented an error that made no sense.

```
Invalid Path - 'C:\Windows\System32'c:\temp'
```

Is there a better way to do this? Or what am I doing wrong? Is there another way to do this? Can this be done with the registry?

Comment: This is not a PowerShell specific code issue. You are simply running a Windows executable in PowerShell, and that requires you to set it up correctly. PowerShell does allow you to run virtually any executable, and that is well documented by MS here: [PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx), and in many articles all over the web and on Youtube. [Quoting is important](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules). The exe is in control.

Answer (score 0):

You could backup security settings using [LGPO.exe](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-security-baselines/lgpo-exe-local-group-policy-object-utility-v1-0/ba-p/701045) and import them with the same tool on other systems.

You can import Security template using:

`LGPO.exe /s "Path to security template file"`

You can create a GPO backup, that also contains Security settings policy, using this command:

`LGPO.exe /b "Path to GPO backup folder"`

It's been working flawlessly for me, it's the same tool that Microsoft Security baseline uses to apply security baseline policies. You can download it from [Microsoft Security Compliance Toolkit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55319)